# approximate the square of 2-norm distance between binary distributions with high probability

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, inequalities, asymptotics

Suppsose we take $m$ samples from a Bernoulli distribution with probability $p$, and $m$ samples from another probability distribution with probability $q$. We want to calculate a statistic $x$ from these samples such that
$$
|x-(p-q)^2|<\epsilon^2
$$
holds with probability at least $1-\delta$.

Can we get the desired probability with $m=O(\frac{\log(1/\delta)}{\epsilon^2})$ samples?

We are particularly interested in the case of $\delta=\frac{1}{2^n}$.

Comment: What is your $x$? Does it have any relation to your sampling? What then do you mean by "obtain $x$"? What do you mean by "Sample $m$ times from **two** [...] distributions"? What do you mean by "binary distributions"?

Comment: @IosifPinelis, does this version make sense to you? I edited the question as I understood it, since I found it clear.

Comment: @MattF. : This version does make sense to me, but it does not look to me the same as the original question. In particular, the original question does not mention any maximization.

Comment: @gondolf : If your sampling and $x$ are defined as in Matt's version, then $m=O(\epsilon^{-4}\ln(1/\delta))$ will do, but of course $m=O(\epsilon^{-2}\ln(1/\delta))$ will not.

Comment: @Pinelis Thanks! Is $\epsilon^{-4}$ tight?

Comment: I believe it's tight, but have not done detailed calculations. If you want to make sure that your comments reach me, use @IosifPinelis, rather than (ampersand)Pinelis.

Comment: I have edited Matt's version of the question to make it closer to the original question.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thanks for your answer.